# Connect a Tape Drive LTO4 to the raspberry pi

Tags: backup

I have a NAS System at home with a RAID-6 and somewhere around 20TB of data.

I have bought a LTO4 external drive that connects over SAS and a few tapes for testing.

A few questions:

- Do you have any ideas on how to connect the RaspberryPi to a SAS (tape) drive ?
- Is there any (opensource) software that could work to automate the backup of my NAS with the Raspi?
- If the Raspi is not the ideal choice, what could be the smallest computer that could handle SAS Drives?

Comment: I think you are going to struggle. Even a cheap, common SAS card for a regular PC or Server is above your budget and those are the common use-cases - hence 'cheap' options. If you are on a budget i'd suggest you look for a second-hand server with an onboard SAS controller and use that. SAS is not a particularly consumer-orientated interconnect (like SATA or USB).

Comment: I have a PCI second hand SAS card. However maybe there is a way to connect a PCI card to a very small form-factor computer without any PCI controler and slot

Comment: Such a `contraption` may exist that provides you a PCI (likely PCI-e ) interface over USB but performance would be horrible. I think you are looking at the wrong device for whats typically an enterprise, not hobbyist solution.

Comment: @JonathanDEKHTIAR can you elaborate on the type of nas system you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest buying a low-power PC in a mini-tower. Just enough of a machine to fit your PCI board in. Anything I have seen has cost more than such a PC.

You can even probably get it used to spend less money, but even a low-end PC will cost under $1,000.

Nothing I've searched for will connect a USB port to a SAS device.

If you *really* wanted to do this, you'd have to do a *lot* of work. I'd start by looking up the PCI bus' electrical specs so that you could connect to it. Then you'd need a power supply to power the tape drive and probably the PCI board.

Then the real work begins: you'd need to write a custom driver.

Just get the PC if there is a driver available. Otherwise you have an interesting-looking paperweight, unless you are very good at electronics and programming and have a lot of spare time. I like these things and are good at them, and I wouldn't try it using a Raspberry Pi unless somebody were willing to throw a lot of money at me.

Comment: I think you have very good points, do you know if a RAID SAS PCIe card can do the job ?
I don't know if a RAID card **must** do RAID volumes or if it can connects HDD or Drives (such as tape drives) normally. Thanks a lot for the help.

For information, I have this SAS Card: Rocket RAID HighPoint 4322

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help further. I have read that some SATA RAID cards will boot if the single drive isn't part of a RAID.

Comment: No problem, if I don't have a better solution by the end of the bounty period related to the RPI I will accept your answer and you will get the reward. Thanks a lot